# Multiple classes that are similar but behave differently

Tags: java, class

I'm designing a system where I have multiple classes that possess many of the same fields/attributes but have different values for each. There are also a number of methods that can be shared between each class but then there are some that only apply to one class or two. What would be the best way to structure this? I originally went with inheritance but the field values are different for each class so I can't see it working. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: "but the field values are different for each class" ... and why would that mean inheritance can't work?

Comment: "I can't see it working" - can you show what you did?

Comment: Could you provide some example of what you want because this is unclear. If you have the same structure but only value are different, make one class and different instance. If your classes have methods that got the same signature but not the same behaviour, implements interfaces. If your classes share a common code, inheritance may be a good choice.

Comment: Say if I used inheritance and declared int x; in the parent class. Do I need to declare this again in each of the subclasses and assign values?

Comment: There are maybe 5 methods that apply to each of the subclasses - assuming that I'm using inheritance - and also a few methods that are specific to each subclass

Comment: The x variable should be protected, then you can assign a new value to it e.g. in the subclass constructor. You cannot redeclare it.

Comment: @JoeLeeson Reguarding your comment about methods. I'd say yes, you'd better use inheritance. Reguarding your comment about x attribute, this is not related to inheritance but to instances.

Comment: Say if I declared a field String colour; in the parent class. How would I access this in the subclass and assign a value?

Comment: colour = "new color";
If the field is declared as protected in the parent class, you can access it in your subclass like it is declared there as private. Maybe you didn't understand fundamental basics of inheritance and object orientation?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Just a quick example: If I had three subclass Dog, Cat, Rabbit and they all had a common method that returned a String value. If I wanted to check for this value in a separate class how would I do that? would it be checkValue(Dog d)  checkValue(Cat c)  checkValue(Rabbit r)  or can I somehow combine this?

Comment: If these three classes are inherited from an Animal class, your method is checkValue(Animal a).